# How to make link not clickable when printing to PDF

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with a table. If a user logs in, they can click on the row headers to enter the edit page. To make the printed version look the same for both logged in and not logged in users, I use CSS to style the link as regular text.

The problem is, that the Save as PDF feature in chrome saves the links with their href, making them open a webpage if clicked on in the saved pdf. Is there any way, to remove this href during this 'print', **other than the obvious way of having two elements and showing only the clickable one in `@media not print` and showing only the non clickable one in `@media print`**?

I prefer not using JavaScript to change the href during printing.

Comment: You could add an extra class to these links and then use a 'display:none' style on your print style sheet.

Comment: @ChelseaStats I should've clarified, that the link is applied to the title for every row (e.g. `<tr><th><a href="?edit=1">Item #1</a></th><td>...`)

Comment: @ChelseaStats Reread this: ...other than the obvious way of having two elements and showing only the clickable one in `@media not print` and showing only the non clickable one in `@media print`?

Comment: sorry my bad. didn't see that detail initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the onclick attribute to open the edit page:

```
<th onclick="location.href='?edit=ID'">Item #1</th>
```

To style it as a link, use the `th[onclick]` CSS selector:

```
@media not print {
    th[onclick], td[onclick] {
        color: #00e;
        text-decoration: underline;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pointer-events`, see here the browser compatibility for that http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events . It will disable your link.

```
@media print {
  a {
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This has no effect for me. The link is not clickable in chrome, but after 'printing' it with 'Save as PDF', the link is clickable again (it is even clickable in the print preview window).

Comment: Try printing this codepen by clicking the button http://codepen.io/TunderScripts/pen/vxYNwE

Comment: That does remove the link. However, if you change the href to e.g. google.com, the link is no longer removed during print.

Comment: You need to use JS , since you cannot alter html with only CSS.

Comment: I know CSS can't alter HTML, I'd just like to know whether there is some way to do this without JS, but with e.g. a special attribute for chrome.

Comment: If you really want to use only css, duplicate the link in the form of a span and hide it for `screen` and show only for `print`. Ex: `<tr><th><a href="?edit=1">Item #1</a><span class="only_print">Item #1</span></th><td>`

Comment: Reread this: ...other than the obvious way of having two elements and showing only the clickable one in `@media not print` and showing only the non clickable one in `@media print`?

Answer (score 0):

use like this remove anchor tag and put div...like

```
 <style>
   #d:active {
    load-url: (http://google.com/
}
    </style>
    <div class="click" id="d" >

    </div>
```

Comment: How would this load a specific website for every row? (My URL is `?edit=ID` where ID is the id of the row in the sql table)